# Git partial commit of staged changes

Tags: git

My current `git status` looks like this:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   docs/file3.org
#       modified:   src/main/R/lib.R
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   docs/file3.org
#       modified:   src/main/R/lib.R
```

I'd like to commit the *staged* changes to `docs/file3.org` first, then the other staged changes.  But if I do `git commit -m '...' docs/file3.org`, it will commit both the staged & unstaged changes to that file.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Or do I need to `stash` my unstaged changes, unstage one of the files, commit the other, restage, commit, and `stash pop`?

Comment: It's possible that the behaviour of `git commit` has changed since you posted this question, but as of December 2015, the command you tried (specifying the paths you wanted to commit) should work. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) of git commit's --only option:

*Make a commit by taking the updated working tree contents of the paths specified on the command line, disregarding any contents that have been staged for other paths. This is the default mode of operation of git commit if any paths are given on the command line, in which case this option can be omitted.*

Comment: I would actually expect `git commit` (without any paths specified) to commit *only staged* modifications. Anyway, another option is using `git gui` for stage and commit operations.

Comment: As for now, it works just fine. It you are uncertain about what changes are going to be in commit, try interactive [staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging), first add/remove desired files to/from staging, then watch diff to check the results

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you only need to commit the staged changes to a file, you can just stash, keeping the indexed changes intact, and committing the file after that.

```
git stash --keep-index #Note that the staged changes also become part of the stash
git commit -m "Commit only one file" docs/file3.org

git commit -m "Commit other staged changed"
git stash pop 
# This may raise CONFLICTS since the stash includes the earlier staged changes.
# In case of conflict, the stash is not popped, so you need to drop it explicitly.
```

Comment: This is basically the flow I outlined in my question, which I was hoping *not* to do. =)  But if it's what we've got, it's what we've got, thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the point of being able to stage partial if you can't split the commit anyway? Using git stash really sounds like a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

What's really weird, is that git-scm book explains staging exactly how you described:

unstaged changes of the same file don't go with commit, only staged changes.

Check it out:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Staging-Modified-Files

I started testing and regardless of what changes of the same file I had staged, all changes went with the commit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're on `master` for all this...

```
git branch whatever
git commit # commit currently staged changes as 'commit1'
git add docs/file3.org
git commit # commit unstaged changes as 'commit2'
```

You'll now have this

```
master
  \
   \--commit1--commit2
```

Now, run `git log` and record the SHAs for 'commit1' and 'commit2'.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick commit2SHA
git cherry-pick commit1SHA
```

Which will give you

```
master--newcommit2--newcommit1
   \
    \--commit1--commit2
```

And then you can destroy the 'whatever' branch

```
git branch -D whatever
```

---

*edit*:

You could also do something similar using the stash:

```
git stash --keep-index  # Save unstaged changes
git stash               # Save staged changes
git stash pop stash@{1} # Pop unstanged changes
git commit ...          # Commit unstanged changes
git stash pop stash@{0} # Pop staged changes
git commit ...          # Commit staged changes
```

Comment: In your first `git commit`, won't that commit both currently staged files?  That's what I'm trying to avoid, I want one set of hunks from one file in my first commit.

Answer (score 1):

[`git stash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-stash) is the best option, combined with.

```
git add --interactive
```

This should allow you to 'revert' (unstage) some files already added to the index.
Then `git stash` would allow you to save those files and restore them.

(See "[`git add --patch` and `--interactive`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-add/)" article for an example)